# Using aggregation in Django with

Tags: django, django-queryset, aggregation

Following is my model:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author_id', default=1)
    source = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='source_id', default=2)
```

User is the django provided model.

Now I need to find out number of articles authored and sourced by each user.

I thought of using story_set with user object:

```
res = User.objects.annotate(Count('story_set'))
```

However, there are two columns in story referencing User. Hence, Django won't know which one to use?

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`story_set` doesn't exist one way or another. That would've been the default `related_name` if you hadn't provided one. Since you did, you have to use those.

```
res = User.objects.annotate(Count('author_id'))
```

OR

```
res = User.objects.annotate(Count('source_id'))
```

So, that's how Django knows the difference.

**FYI:** if you *had* used the default (so you accessed stories via `.story_set.all()`, you don't use the "_set" part in queries.  It would just be `Count('story')`.

Comment: My doubt is how will Django know about author_id attribute if it doesn't exist in User. It exists in Story.

Comment: That's what `related_name` does. It defines the relationship on the opposite site. If `Story` has users then `User` has `story_set`. Or, in your case, `author_id` and `source_id` (which is why you should change those to something more meaningful like `author_set` and `source_set`). This is the magic of Django.

Answer (score 1):

the reason django makes you specify a `related_name` is exactly for this reason. you want `Count('author_id')` instead of `Count('story_set')` (and you should probably give these better names, e.g. `author_set`)

Answer (score 0):

```
res = User.objects.annotate(num_authored=Count('author_id')).annotate(num_sourced=Count('source_id'))
res[0].num_authored
res[0].num_sourced
```

If you want both the number of authored and number of sourced articles in one query. You might want more appropriate related names, like "authored" and "sourced".